# Remote trigger of Canon 420EX Speedlite

Tags: off-camera-flash

I'm using 2 x Yongnuo YN560 IV speedlites triggered by a Yongnuo YN560 TX II wireless Manual Flash Controller. Works perfectly. I'd like to add my Canon 420EX into the mix but I can't seem to find a wireless trigger for the 420 that will work with Yongnuo controller. I'm looking at the Yongnuo RF603 but I can't see anywhere whether or not it can be triggered from the flash controller.

It's a bit complicated, I know. Thank in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The specs for the YN560TX II say the compatible receivers are the RF-605, RF-603 II, RF-602.

With these triggers you will only be able to fire the flash. You will not have ETTL, HSS, or remote control the power level or zoom of the flash.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try to get simple control using my 602RX

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it, but the 420EX is a terrible candidate to use off-camera in any radio or non-TTL scheme (like the Yongnuo YN-560 gear), because it has no Manual mode.  You can only really control its power in TTL, and Yongnuo manual triggers (like the YN-560-TX and RF-60x triggers) do not communicate TTL.

If you use it with the YN-560-TX/RF-602/RF-603/RF-603II/RF-605 triggers, it will only fire at full power.

You also can't really use Yongnuo's TTL add-on triggers (the YN-622s) with their respective transmitters because the 420EX is too old to do camera menu communication (only the 430EX II/580EX II and later speedlights can do that), and that's the communication protocol the 622s use to do power control. You'd only have TTL control, and that wouldn't work for triggering the YN-560s.

There are reasons today we tell people to start with Godox TT600 speedlights and a Godox X system transmitter. Just me, but forget about using the 420EX, and get another YN-560IV.

Comment: Thanks. If I can’t get enough control with 602RX and something to attenuate the flash I’ll go down the road of another 560IV

Comment: @MartinC, [The best way to thank someone for an answer is to accept or upvote it](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This will also gain you rep as well. If you plan to stick around, take some time to read [the Tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how SE works.

Comment: You can control it with a 622 if it's an EX II model. Not that the OP want's to change transmitters for this flash anyway.

Comment: @Robin, yeah but the 420EX _isn't_ an EXII model. They'd have to change the flash as well for that control. You'll note I mentioned this in paragraph 3. :)